# Mobile and HTML Manifest Cache Performance

Tags: ios, html, web-applications, cache-manifest

I'm considering developing a web app that allows users to create a calendar of deadlines based on events stored online using the HTML5 manifest to store some basic user information. Before starting however, it would useful to know how robust the manifest is:

- If a user clears their mobile Safari cache will it delete any webapp manifests as well?
- Is there a way for a webapp to send unique indentifying information to a server so user info can be stored online without requiring a login?

Thank you very much. Any advice on such development would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your first point, clearing Safari's cache *will* remove manifest data, but not for sites that have been added to the home screen as a 'web app'.